# References and lifetimes

Tags: rust

I just started experimenting with Rust and want to convert this simple C++ program to Rust:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <stdint.h>

using namespace std;

struct Game;

struct Player {
  Player(Game* game, uint32_t health) : game(game), health(health) {
  }

  uint32_t health;
  Game* game;
};

struct Game {
  Player& new_player() {
    players.emplace_back(this, 100);
    return players.back();
  }

  vector<Player> players;
};


int main() {
  Game g;
  g.new_player().health -= 10;
  g.new_player().health -= 20;

  for (auto p : g.players) {
    cout << "player health = " << p.health << endl;
  }

  return 0;
}
```

This is my hacky Rust attempt:

```
struct Player<'a> {
  health: i32,
  game: &'a mut Game<'a>
}

struct Game<'a> {
  players: Vec<Player<'a>>
}

impl <'a> Game<'a> {
  fn new() -> Game<'a> {
    Game { players: Vec::new() }
  }

  fn new_player(&'a mut self) -> &'a mut Player<'a> {
    unsafe {
      // Ugly unsafe hack to fix compiler error
      let ps: *mut Game<'a> = self;
      self.players.push(Player { health: 100, game: &mut *ps });
      self.players.mut_last().unwrap()
    }
  }
}

fn main() {
  let mut g = Game::new();
  g.new_player().health -= 10;

  // Compiler error about multiple borrows
  g.new_player().health -= 20;

  // Compiler error about multiple borrows
  for p in g.players.mut_iter() {
    println!("player health = {}", p.health);
  }
}
```

However I use unsafe code (which I hope is not necessary) and run into problems with references and lifetimes which I really don't know how to fix. What's the idiomatic way of writing this code in Rust? Or is the Rust type system currently too limited to express it in a safe way?

Btw, I'm using "rustc 0.12.0-pre-nightly (6bb72600c 2014-08-05 00:01:28 +0000)".

Answer (score 0):

It is not sound for you to have multiple mutable references to an object at the same time, but you have caused this to happen in your unsafe code. This is a memory safety bug waiting to happen, for you have broken the invariants about mutable references.

If you wish to be able to access it from multiple places, you will need to use something like `Rc<RefCell<Game>>` (make the one inside the `Player` a `Weak<RefCell<Game>>`), and you’ll still need to ensure at runtime that you don’t go taking two mutable references to the underlying `Game` at a time.

If you can avoid the need to store a reference to the `Game` in a `Player`, that would also solve things.

Comment: Thanks. I figured out that the lifetimes in my code didn't really make sense as the Player reference can live on even when it's removed from Game.players. The reference lifetime should rather be the same as the time the object is still present in the container which would require a pretty complex lifetime specification (not possible in Rust I think).